# Передать значение из js в php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Есть три файла: `index.php`, `sript.js` и `load.php`

В индексе при клике на селектор через аякс (`sript.js`) загружается `load.php`. После чего, при успехе `sript.js`, делает вывод значения в `index`  через `innerHtml`.

Подскажите, как в индексе мне запихнуть значение `innerHtml` в переменную, чтобы дальше использовать?

Comment: Можно использовать [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). В callback-функцию передастся ответ от вашего `load.php` как параметр.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос некорректен. Тебе не в PHP нужно передать, а в переменную JS страницы, сгенерированной на PHP. Если я правильно понял, конечо.
Делай так:

```
var perem = getElementById(...).innerHTML; // Вместо getElementById  может быть любой другой метод поиска элемента
```

или с помощью jQuery:

```
var perem = $(...).html();
```

Хотя, зачем через innerHTML. В script.js создавай переменную, она будет глобальна и видна в index
Если и передаешь через innerHTML, то не в тело самой страницы, а например, в специально созданный DIV и оттуда выдергиваешь.