# PHP. Узнать название файла

Tags: php, массивы

Есть директория, в ней mp3 файлы, я её сканирую, получаю массив с названием файлов (это файлы mp3, проигрывающиеся плеером JavaScript). Как узнать имя файла, который слушает пользователь в PHP? Через JavaScript я могу получить имя файла, но мне оно нужно в PHP.

Просто передать переменную из JS в PhP

Прошу помощи!

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke

Comment: Ну так получите в js и отправьте в php

Comment: а как отправлять из JS в php?

Comment: не из PhP в JS , а наоборот

Comment: из PhP я знаю как в JS передавать

Comment: Во-первых Java и JavaScript это разные языки, во-вторых скорректируйте вопрос и добавьте код, что бы было более понятно. В третьих нельзя просто передать переменную между чем-то и чем-то не понимая что это такое. PHP выполняется на сервере, JavaScript на клиенте

Comment: Опишите подробнее проблему/задачу. В какой момент вам нужно получить наименование файла? Как только человек начал слушать? Важно ли определять каким пользователем "слушается файл"? В итоге что вы хотите сделать - вносить какие-то данные в БД на сервере после получения этого наименования? На сервере должен быть PHP скрипт который обработает ваш ajax запрос, который вы пошлете при помощи JavaScript.. если конечно я правильно догадываюсь что вам нужно сделать..

Comment: Важно определить каким пользователем , его логин хранится в сессии

Comment: получить при нажатии пользователем на кнопку

Comment: и после его нажатия данный файл копируется в его директорию

Comment: имеющую имя , такое же как его логин

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Передать значение из js в php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/436032/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-js-%d0%b2-php)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/773083/176064

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, понял ли я вас верно, но я так понимаю, трудностей на стороне клиента (JavaSсript) с получением наименования файла у вас нет, проблемы именно с отправкой. В определенный момент вы получаете наименование файла, и хотите эту строчку отправить.. В таком случае вам нужно использовать ajax. Тут есть два варианта

**Библиотека jQuery**

```
    var yourFileName = 'наименование_файла_которое_получили'
    $.ajax({
        url : 'ваш_скрипт.php?наименование='+yourFileName,
        async: true,
        success: function (response) {
            //Здесь обработка ответа
        },
        error: function () {
            //Здесь обработка ошибки
        }
    });
```

**Чистый JavaScript**

```
var yourFileName = 'наименование_файла_которое_получили'
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET", "ваш_скрипт.php?наименование="+yourFileName, true);
ajax.send();

ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
        //Здесь обработка ответа
    }
    else{
        //Здесь обработка ошибки
    }
};
```

Далее ваш PHP скрипт, который работает на сервере, должен обработать запрос GET. То есть нужно извлечь переменную из массив $_GET

```
$musicFileName = $_GET['наименование'];
```

Ну и далее можно делать все что необходимо с этим значением...